# Change Constraint from iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I'm working with size classes in xcode and can't figure out how to change a layout constraint between the iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus.  Their size class is both Compact-Width Regular-Height so I'm a bit stumped.

Basically I want the button pictured below to have a top constraint of 446 for iPhone 7 and 500 for iPhone 7 Plus.  I'm trying to do this through Interface Builder because this View Controller is from a pod.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you can't achieve an almost identical result using percentages ? (e.g. button y position = 75% of view height )

Comment: Do you want to manipulate the *top constraint*? Wouldn't it be easier to constrain the button to be the same distance from the *bottom* on each device?

Comment: @deadbeef can you do button y position through Interface Builder

Comment: What you are trying is totally against the way layout constraints should be used. Instead of 446 vs. 500 you should be calculating the coordinates depending on the height. And what happens on iPhone 5? And once you get to the iPad, you're totally in trouble with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

link the top constraint

@IBOutlet weak var topCons: NSLayoutConstraint!

and

fire this

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    if screenSize.height > 700 // iphone 7 plus
    {
        topCons.constant = 500
    }

    else
    {
        topCons.constant = 446
    }
```

Comment: this would have worked however I'm trying to specifically do this through interface builder

Comment: I not think you can do 446 for iPhone 7 and 500 iPhone 7 Plus  through interface builder only but I wish some one help you if there are way for that